# Может ли вызов функции библиотеки в многопотоке держать остальные потоки на python?

Tags: python, многопоточность, асинхронность, pool

Есть вот такой код многопоточного получения текстов со страниц:

```
import html2text
from readability import Document
from html2text import HTML2Text

def get_article(files): #на входе список ссылок
        with open(files) as file:
               links = [row.rstrip() for row in file]
        for link in sitemap: #для каждой ссылки
                response = requests.get(link, timeout = 10) #получаем код странцы
                doc = Document(response.text) #преобразуем полученное в DOM
                h = HTML2Text() #вызываем html2text для преобразования кода статьи в текст
                h.ignore_links = True
                h.ignore_images = True
                title = doc.title() #получаем заголовок статьи
                article = h.handle(doc.summary()) #получаем текст статьи
    
 with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as pool:
    pool.map(lambda sitemap: get_article(sitemap), files)
```

Вопрос может ли вызов функций для обработки кода страницы, получения заголовка и текста держать остальные потоки или в каждом потоке выполняется независимо? Если да, то как можно это исправить?

Comment: а что значит "держать другие потоки"? не давать им исполнятся? управлять другими потоками? владеть потоками?

Comment: Не давать им закончить работу. То есть не может ли получаться так что другие потоки ждут пока первый не закончит работу с html2text и readability?

Comment: Вам нужны мьютексы и условные переменные. Или дать им другую работу.

Comment: Так а в files что - список списков? И попробуйте ещё pool.imap, чтобы разная скорость обработки не так сильно влияла

Comment: А вообще вы пробовали логировать происходящее, чтобы понятно было когда и что запустилось и закончилось?

Comment: В files список файлов со ссылками, дописал в код открытие файла со ссылками. Логгирование внутри потока по времени добавлял-иногда идут задержки после title = doc.title() и article = h.handle(doc.summary()). Поэтому и возник вопрос.

Comment: возможно, у Вас слишком много потоков, и нужный поток просто не получает время тогда, когда Вы это ожидаете

Comment: >>И попробуйте ещё pool.imap - можете дать пример? В python еще совсем зеленый.

Comment: @CrazyElf у него https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html похоже, там нет imap.

Comment: @bobr А как выглядит "_идут задержки после title = doc.title() и article = h.handle(doc.summary())_" ? поставьте скажем отладочную печать перед requests.get, сразу после, о том что получили данные, потом скажем перед title, перед article и после article. И посмотрите, например во время пока один поток выполняет title другие потоки что нибудь свое делают или нет. И кстати я в вашем прошлом вопросе спрашивал какой у вас характер нагрузки, все ядра сильно используются или скажем только одно на 100% это может много подсказать о том, в чем тут проблема

Comment: @Mike - вспомни о GIL - зависший тред блокирует остальные, точнее блокирует всё кроме  времени ожидания requests.get

Comment: @eri Я вот как раз к этому и писал и в прошлый раз и сейчас. У меня стойкое подозрение, что функции разбора документа (title и получение текста) не отпускают GIL и поэтому любые потоки тут пользы не приносят. Но я не могу подтвердить ни опровергнуть данное подозрение, потому что ТС не сообщает даже о характере нагрузки, а хочется еще узнать происходит ли что то еще пока работает скажем title

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код может падать от таймаута. таймаут стоит, а обработки нет.

В старом экзекуторе можно сделать так. Новые треды будут запускаться по мере освобождения старых. Ответы будут сформированы в итератор, который надо пройти.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

with Pool(num_threads) as pool:
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(get_article, files):
        pass
```

В этом варианте я бы в тредах оставил только requests, а парсинг уже делал под этим фором (всеравно gil)

Или если ответы не важны совсем, как у вас в коде нет return.

```
pool = Pool(num_threads)
ar = pool.map_async(get_article, files)
pool.join()
```

*Убрал ненужную лямбду.*

И ещё одно замечание - файлы обычно читаются быстро, но так как имеют разный размер, то один файл может обрабатываться когда есть свободные воркеры. я бы смешал содержимое файлов через генератор.

```
def link_gen(files):
    for name in files:
        with open(files) as file:
            for row in file:
                yield row.rstrip() 

def get_article(link):
            response = requests.get(link, timeout = 10) #получаем код странцы
            doc = Document(response.text) #преобразуем полученное в DOM
            h = HTML2Text() #вызываем html2text для преобразования кода статьи в текст
            h.ignore_links = True
            h.ignore_images = True
            title = doc.title() #получаем заголовок статьи
            article = h.handle(doc.summary()) #получаем текст статьи        


pool.map_async(get_article, link_gen(files))
```

И о том что писал выше - экономим память не особо теряя в производительности:

```
def  get_article(link):
    try:
        response = requests.get(link, timeout = 10)
        return response 
    except:
        return


with Pool(num_threads) as pool:
    for response in pool.imap_unordered(get_article, link_gen(files)):
        if response:
            doc = Document(response.text) #преобразуем полученное в DOM
            h = HTML2Text() #вызываем html2text для преобразования кода статьи в текст
            h.ignore_links = True
            h.ignore_images = True
            title = doc.title() #получаем заголовок статьи
            article = h.handle(doc.summary()) #получаем текст статьи
```

Чтоб загрузить все ядра нужны не треды, а процессы. Стоит ли их нагружать зависит от разницы во времени скачивания и обработки. если скачивается быстрее - то убери слово `.dummy` и модуль начнет работать на процессах.
Конечно обработку верни обратно в функцию.

Стоит добавить chunksize. Значение выбирай примерно 5% от количества ссылок деленное на количество процессов.